# How put put one transparent button over mapview?

Tags: java, android, button, android-mapview

I would like to put transparent (map visible under it) button over mapview?
How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this on the button
android:background="@null" or
android:background="@android:color/transparent" 
EDIT:
to place over use a relative layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/google_maps"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:apiKey="@string/maps_key"/>
<Button android:id="@+id/googlemaps_select_location"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="Select"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap the map in a FrameLayout or something. Then add a button to the FrameLayout and use `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` for Right, Left, Top and Bottom. The button will then align it's edges with the edges of the FrameLayout, which should be wrapping the map.