# Why my Map fragment return null?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11626182/how-put-put-one-transparent-button-over-mapview) and similar posts.

To me it seems that I do everything correctly.

Still,

```
SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);`
```

returns NULL.

**activty_map.xml**

```
<FrameLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<fragment
android:id="@+id/map"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
/>

<Button 
android:id="@+id/startgeo"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Set Geo"
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
android:layout_gravity="right"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**Code in my Activity:**

```
    setContentView(R.layout.activty_map);
    SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map); //RETURNS NULL !!!
    map = mapFrag.getMap();
```

Comment: I would think that getMap() might return null, sure that is not it?

Comment: how do you add fragment?

Comment: @nikis do I need to add the fragment in such a circumstance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19219255/supportmapfragment-getmap-returns-null) by some other devs, google maps take some while to load. That is why you need to call your map initialization code after some delay (lets say 500ms).

For example:

```
setContentView(R.layout.activty_map);

new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        SupportMapFragment mapFrag = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map); //should'nt be null after 500ms
        map = mapFrag.getMap();
    }
}, 500);
```

Moreover, I would suggest you to rely on `onResume` method for confirm completion of loading.

Comment: calling in in onResume() did not help :-((

Comment: try `onResumeFragments`

Comment: The idea is that map loading takes time and its reference should only be initiated once the loading is done. It is the same as we bind Services in android - which is asynchronous.

Comment: neither, NULL again :-((

Comment: did you try adding delay by using `Handler`? paste some more code

Answer (score 1):

Rather than just posting it using some arbitrary delay you can be sure the fragment will be available in in onResumeFragments, #[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onResumeFragments()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#onResumeFragments%28%29)